# How to make one option active and disable the others in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to make one option disabled while the other would be disabled and vice versa? I tried out adding two functions but that doesn't seem to work. The problem which I am facing is that while I select the first option, the button gets enabled but on selecting the other option, the previous option remains to get enabled. How to solve this query?

```
<option id="display" onclick="display1(); display2()">Option 1</option>
    <script>
        var val1="Option 1";
        var val2=document.getElementById('display').value;
        if (val1==val2) {
            function display1() {
                document.getElementById('hgt').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('wdt').disabled = false;
            }
        } else if (val1!=val2) {
            function display2() {
                document.getElementById('hgt').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('wdt').disabled = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
<option id="text1" onclick="text1(); text2()">Option 2</option>
    <script>
        var val3="Option 2";
        var val4= document.getElementById('text1').value;
        if (val3==val4) {
            function text1() {
                document.getElementById('write').disabled = false;
            }
        } else if (val3!=val4) {
            function text2() {
                document.getElementById('text1').disabled = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</select></br></br>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Unless you set a selectbox to multiple, then it only shows one active selection. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: Functions in an if statement are really really bad..

Answer (score 0):

You have no opening select tag, also your code is interwoven with your html. You might want to clean that up a bit

However, you can do something like this.

```js
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

var option1 = document.getElementById('option1');

var option2 = document.getElementById('option2');

select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {


  if (this.value === 'option1') {

    option2.setAttribute('disabled', true)

    console.log(option2);
  }
  if (this.value === 'option2') {

    option1.setAttribute('disabled', true)

    console.log(option2);
  }


})
```

```html
<select>
<option> defualt</option>
<option id="option1">option1</option>
<option id="option2">option2</option>
</select>
</br>
</br>
```

Answer (score -1):

test not use the `document.getElementById('hgt').disabled = true;` but use this instead 
disable:`document.getElementById('hgt').style.display = "none";`
activate:`document.getElementById('hgt').style.display = "block";`

Comment: `display:none` would hide it, not disable it.

Comment: whas this helpful

Comment: style="display: none;" is not css is html

Comment: `element.style` effectively sets a css property so, yeah, what you're doing is equivalent to css's `display: none`. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: no it is element.style = "none"; i have it on my website/localhost

Comment: oh really? https://jsfiddle.net/szn33q4L/2/ because the second button doesn't seem to work on my machine. (EDIT: correct link)